# Can I port linux kernel 3.10 on raspberry pi 3?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi3

I have build linux kernel 4.6 for raspberrypi 3 (64 bit architecture). Can linux versions <= 4.0 be also be build on rpi 3?

Comment: Seems like you don't understand the meaning of *port*. *"I have ported linux kernel 4.6..."* -- More likely you simply *built* a kernel image from existing source code. In the professional world, "porting a kernel" means "to *develop* code (esp. the initialization and core drivers) for a previously unsupported processor/SoC/platform/board". The answer to your question is "yes", if you know how.   See http://www.embedded.com/design/connectivity/4023297/Linux-Porting-Guide

Comment: thank u for the clarification. document is really helpful..